# Find $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x - \sin x }{x^3}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I tried this question using this method

$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x - \sin x }{x^3}&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x}{x\cdot x^2} - \frac{\sin x }{x\cdot x^2}&& \left[\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x}x=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1\right]\\&=\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac1{x^2}-\frac1{x^2}\right)\\&=0\end{align}$

but the answer is 1/2.
[Here is the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lLcp.jpg)

I think I am doing some mistakes.
Can anyone please point it out?

Comment: We can't find your mistakes without seeing the work.

Comment: I have attached the image

Comment: @RossMillikan,  "here is the question" is his work

Comment: $\infty-\infty=0$ is not correct. Do not split the given function into two separate terms.

Comment: if lim f,lim g exist then lim f+g=lim f+lim g and  lim fg=lim f $\times$ lim g

Comment: Ohh! Thanks, I got it.

Comment: That means you need to use more terms: until the terms with $x^3$ to make the constant term. Higher-order terms will have a limit of $0$ as $x \to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Maclaurin expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Trigonometric_functions) we get
$$
\frac{\tan x - \sin x}{x^3}
= \frac{(x+\frac13x^3+O(x^5)) - (x-\frac16x^3+O(x^5)}{x^3}
= \frac{\frac12x^3+O(x^5)}{x^3}
= \frac12+O(x^2)
\to \frac12
$$
as $x\to0.$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** As mentioned in the comments, you can't just say $\infty-\infty=0$. You need to go back to the original expression and do some manipulation. For example, give $\tan x$ as a factor in the numerator:
$$\tan x-\sin x=\tan x-\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\cos x=\tan x(1-\cos x)$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

To answer this you need to first use L’hopital’s Rule three times:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ \tan(x)-\sin(x)}{x^3}$$
$$= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ \sec^2(x)-\cos(x)}{3x^2}$$
$$= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ 2\sec^2(x)\tan(x)+\sin(x)}{6x}$$
$$= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ 4\sec^2(x)\tan^2(x)+2\sec^4(x)+\cos(x)}{6}$$
$$=\frac{0+2+1}{6}=\frac{1}{2}
.
$$

Your main mistake is that you tried subtracting two functions that tend to $\infty$ when $x$ goes to zero.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\frac{\tan (x) - \sin (x) }{x^3}=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\frac{1}{\cos(x)}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}.$$
Now apply Hospital on the last factor.